# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while reading image in apache pdfbox

Tags: java, image, exception, pdfbox, heap-memory

I am creating a pdf using Apache Pdfbox api. While trying to read image, getting Heap Space issue on the below code:

```
    PDXObjectImage ximage = null;

    InputStream is1 = new ClassPathResource(appProp.getProperty("fon1")).getInputStream();
    InputStream is2 = new ClassPathResource(appProp.getProperty("font2")).getInputStream();

    font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc,is1);
    font1 = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(doc,is2);
    BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read(new ClassPathResource(appProp.getProperty("Logo")).getInputStream());
    ximage = new PDPixelMap(doc, awtImage);
    float scale = 0.009f;
```

StackTrace:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space] with root cause
>
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at
>   java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.(DataBufferByte.java:92) at
>   java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(ComponentSampleModel.java:445)
>   at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:941) at
>   javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:1074)
>   at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2892) at
>   com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1090)
>
> at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1058)
>
> at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1462)
>
> at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1357)

Exception occurred while doing ImageIO.read, but not every-time. It's occurring randomly. Same is working fine while running the code in local machine but it's failing in Dev region.

Can somebody help me in resolving the issue.

Thanks,

Comment: stacktrace could be helpful

Comment: *"Exception occurred while doing ImageIO.read"* - that line does not appear PDFBox related. Or do you want to imply that the two TTFs loaded before require too much memory?

Comment: @RobOhRob stacktrace added.

Comment: @mkl Didn't get you.I am not implying anything but obviously issue is related to memory while reading the image.

Comment: Set a larger -Xmx value, e.g. -Xmx2g .

Comment: @Tilman Yes that's a option but if there is something in code that is not right, i want to correct that

Comment: Maybe the image is huge. Or different java versions. The code looks OK (if you're comfortable using an outdated PDFBox version).

Comment: What's the name of your class? At which line did the stacktrace say that the error occurred?

Comment: @Rob it happened at ImageIO.read(). So either this is a big image, or he was already low on memory before.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? I have same problem.

Comment: @GhostDede It was due to big size of logo file...it was resolved once we reduce the image size.

Comment: Don't forget to close your inputStream objects (three in the code above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue after using the image of lesser size.